# How to enable components to resize according to the change in the form size?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I made a simple button based form for a particular resolution, say, 800*480.

I want the buttons to automatically resize themselves when used on a higher resolution.

I have **six buttons of equal size** placed as shown and I have used the following **anchor** properties

```
[TOP,LEFT]          [TOP,RIGHT]

[LEFT]               [RIGHT]

[BOTTOM,LEFT]       [BOTTOM,RIGHT]
```

I want the buttons to increase their size as well. On the higher resolution, the screen looks empty as all the buttons shift toward the periphery of the screen

If I use the following config, the buttons overlap each other

```
[TOP,LEFT,RIGHT]          [TOP,RIGHT,LEFT]

[LEFT,RIGHT]               [RIGHT,LEFT]

[BOTTOM,LEFT,RIGHT]       [BOTTOM,LEFT,RIGHT]
```

What should I do?

I am using Visual C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `TableLayoutPanel` to your form, with 3 rows and 2 columns.

Set `Dock` property to `Fill`

Put each of your buttons in a cell of the `TableLayoutPanel` and set their `Dock` property to `Fill`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set all of your buttons' **"Anchor"** properties to **Top, Bottom, Left, Right**.

This keeps them in place, but also resizes them. Make sure the buttons' **"AutoSize"**-property is set to **false**.